# HttpResponseBase.Headers are empty when running test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq to create a `Mock<HttpResponseBase>` to test an `FileResult` I'm creating for my MVC2 application.

In the `WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)` method of the `FileResult`, I have the following code at the end:

```
// Write the final output with specific encoding.
response.OutputStream.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", encoding);
```

It will use `utf-8` or `gzip` depending on the encoding from the request's `Accept-Encoding` header.

So then in my test, I setup my `Mock<HttpResponseBase>` like so:

```
var mockResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
mockResponse.Setup(r => r.OutputStream).Returns(new MemoryStream());
mockResponse.Setup(r => r.Headers).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
```

But when I actually check that the header has been set, `Content-Encoding` *always* returns null:

```
var response = mockResponse.Object;
Assert.AreEqual("utf-8", response.Headers["Content-Encoding"]);
```

The weird thing is that the OutputStream gets the data written to it and I can assert that it's writing the correct value.

The odd thing is that when I actually debug the `FileResult` in a web project, the header is properly sent.

Does anyone have some insight to this? I can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: Can you include more code regarding the Moq setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up just mocking the `AppendHeader` method to forcefully add the header to the `HttpResponseBase`'s headers:

```
mockResponse
    .Setup(r => r.AppendHeader(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((string k, string v) => mockResponse.Object.Headers.Add(k, v));
```

I suspect that there is something further down inside the call of `AppendHeader` that doesn't like adding headers without an actual `HttpResponseBase` in place.

If there is a better idea, feel free to suggest. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are having is to do with the fact that you are trying to partially mock `HttpResponseBase` class. Writing to output stream works because the property (`OutputStream` in this case) is mocked and is accessed from SUT (System Under Test).

However, when you mock `Headers` property, it is only that property that is getting mocked and not `AppendHeader`, which is what your SUT actually does. The default mocks created by Moq simply stub all methods and properties as returning default values, so `AppendHeader` doesn't actually do anything.

There are two solutions to this, first one is purely interaction testing and is my preferred approach. Do not mock `Headers`, but instead verify `AppendHeader`.

```
Mock<HttpResponseBase> responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
//the rest of response setup
FileResult sut = new MyFileResult();
sut.WriteFile(responseMock.Object);
responseMock.Verify(response=>response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "utf8"));
```

Second approach is to utilise Moq's partial mocking, which would make the mock object call actual class' methods, unless they have been set up explicitly.

```
Mock<HttpResponseBase> responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(){ CallBase = true };
//the rest of response setup
FileResult sut = new MyFileResult();
sut.WriteFile(responseMock.Object);
Assert.AreEqual("utf-8", responseMock.Object.Headers["Content-Encoding"]);
```

I would prefer the first version by a thin margin as you are testing your interaction with the framework. The second version is more of a state-based test, so theoretically you don't even need a mock, you could just use the actual class. In case of `HttpResponseBase`, however, it almost makes sense as its constructor is protected, so by creating a mock, you are basically deriving from it inline, without having to manually write a test double.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize that Moq was stubbing `AppendHeader`. Setting `CallBase=true` shows that. I like your idea of verifying that it *did* set the header, but it doesn't *really* make sure that the header is set with the final state being sent (like you said). I could accidentally call another `AppendHeader` and then overwrite it afterward with another call (though I guess I could *verify* this as well). Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the setup code provided(not sure if its a typo), I think it should read as follows

```
var Response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
Response.Setup(r => r.OutputStream).Returns(new MemoryStream()); 
Response.Setup(r => r.Headers).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
```

Comment: Yeah it was a typo in the post. I had named it differently in the code in the post than the actual code I was using. In the "real" code, it's a property called "Response" of a "MockHttpContext" class that I created. The above code is the *only* part that modifies the `Mock<HttpResponseBase>`.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - my answer is moot then

Comment: This worked. Interesting how you have to use a `MemoryStream` to set up the headers. Tried a hundred other things before this. Thanks, @Ahmad.